# Ceiling fan lightbulb replacement

Tags: fans, light

[image]

I have tried unscrewing the top four screws and the bottoms four. I have no ideas left on how to take the glass off eithlut basically completely disassembling the fan.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Do you know the make/model of the fan?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in that no sane manufacturer would build something that would require disassembly of the fan to change the light bulbs.

This looks like a split glass assembly, you might have a locking ring above the fan blades, if it is a locking ring type unscrew the locking ring and it would drop down and allow you to slide one glass side out in order to change the bulbs. You might have to remove the blades to do this - but I can not be sure.

Since you do not list the make and model it is difficult to give more specifics.

Answer (score -1):

Try finding the fan's model number on the housing.  Look up the model information from the manufacturer's website.  This may be a sealed LED light housing.  Personally, I do not like sealed LED lights for ANYTHING.  They NEVER last as long as they claim.
Ok, enough ranting - if it is a sealed LED light fixture your only options are to get another LED light kit from the manufacturer or install an entire new fan/light combo.  Another reason NOT to purchase any fixtures (fan or otherwise) with sealed LEDs.  Always purchase fixtures with bulbs - if you prefer LED then purchase the bulb and screw in. :)

Comment: Please save your personal vendetta against sealed LED lights for someone who asks about them, and stick to answering the question asked, not inserting a diatribe/rant that does not answer the question.